# EMA function (pack TTR) - Invalid N

Tags: r, xts, technical-indicator

I'm having some trouble to create a loop using EMA function.

```
for(i in c(1,2,3)){ 

paste("Q",i,"$",tick[i],"_EMA10", sep="") = EMA(na.locf(paste("Q",i,"$",tick[i]),sep=""),10)

}
```

Where `tick = c(AAPL,MSFT,NQ)` and `Q1`, `Q2`, `Q3` are xts tables, hence the objective of this loop is to run through all the xts tables, take each value of colums as input and create new column with the values on the xts tables.

Expected result would be as if i run individually below:

```
Q1$AAPL_EMA10 <- EMA(na.locf(Q1$AAPL), 10)
```

Problem is that i get error "Invalid N" and I cannot seem to sort it out. Could you please help out?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing some weird stuff:

```
paste("Q",i,"$",tick[i])
[1] "Q 2 $ MSFT"
```

is getting passed to `EMA` (even after passing the string into `na.locf`), and `EMA` expects an xts object.

This achieves what you want, tidying things up a bit:

```
library(quantmod)
tick <- c("AAPL","MSFT","NQ")
getSymbols(tick)

for (i in 1:3) { 
  sym <- tick[i]
  x <- get(sym, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  x <- merge(x, EMA(Cl(x), 10))
  assign(x = sym, value = x, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

tail(AAPL)
# AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted      EMA
# 2018-01-05    173.44    175.37   173.05     175.00    23660000        175.00 172.6937
# 2018-01-08    174.35    175.61   173.93     174.35    20567800        174.35 172.9948
# 2018-01-09    174.55    175.06   173.41     174.33    21584000        174.33 173.2376
# 2018-01-10    173.16    174.30   173.00     174.29    23959900        174.29 173.4289
# 2018-01-11    174.59    175.49   174.49     175.28    18667700        175.28 173.7655
# 2018-01-12    176.18    177.36   175.65     177.09    25226000        177.09 174.3700
```

Instead of having individually named objects Q1, Q1, Q3 (or the names of the symbols instead as the variable names, in my example above), you may want to reconsider how you handle the data.  An example below should make this clearer.

It might be easier to put your per symbol data into a list, with each element containing the data for a particular symbol.   Then you can easily apply operations across your batch of symbols (which might get very large).

```
r <- lapply(X = tick, FUN = function(sym) {
  x <- get(sym, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  x <- merge(x, EMA(Cl(x), 10))
  x
})


lapply(r, tail, n = 1)
# [[1]]
# AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted    EMA  EMA.1
# 2018-01-12    176.18    177.36   175.65     177.09    25226000        177.09 174.37 174.37
# 
# [[2]]
# MSFT.Open MSFT.High MSFT.Low MSFT.Close MSFT.Volume MSFT.Adjusted      EMA    EMA.1
# 2018-01-12     88.67     89.78    88.45       89.6    24236500          89.6 87.72638 87.72638
# 
# [[3]]
# NQ.Open NQ.High NQ.Low NQ.Close NQ.Volume NQ.Adjusted      EMA    EMA.1
# 2018-01-12    4.03    4.03   3.88     3.89   1034400        3.89 3.988761 3.988761
```